# Should I use "people" for non-human creatures with humane mannerisms?

Tags: creature-design, terminology, people

I have an elf/fairy-like creature in my book called faeries, and I don't know what to call them in large groups. When I'm narrating, the word "people" sounds a bit strange to me since I associate "people" with "humans," but the faeries look and act on the basic level that a human does (with the added presence of magic).

Am I overthinking the use of "people" or should I use another term?

(I would/only use "people" when not saying "everyone," "faeries," or another broad term)

Comment: This is a writing problem (there is writing.SE for that) and it is a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: Since fairies are also called "the fair folk" it would be appropriate to use "folk" if you are not happy with "people".

Comment: This depends on your definition of "people". Since the only "people" that exist in our world are humans, we tend to think of those terms as synonymous. But it's possible in a world with aliens or fantasy creatures, "people" would just mean anyone who was an intelligent sentient being. Especially since "people" even here has the added definition of a term used to describe specific groups or cultures (like you might say "the Cherokee People", or "the Irish People")...

Comment: ...Generally those who are trying to avoid applying the term people to other groups are the ones who want to see others as inferior. Which is also fine, depending on what your world looks like! Very possible that one race would refuse to call another race "people" because they don't want to admit they have worth or even equal standing as fellow sentient beings. So essentially, it's all context, and depends on how you chose to define the word. Its really up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a good reason not to, I would say to go ahead. I'm writing a story which is in the similar position of a race of aliens who behave almost exactly like humans, so I just call them "people" (but I'm careful not to use "humans" which would be pushing it too far). I can understand "people" is an odd term but I'm sure I've at least read fantasy creatures like these speaking of "my people" so I don't see why not go another step further to calling the members of that people "people".

So here, as I see it, are your options:

1. **Call them people.** As I said, I don't see a problem with this other than it not being technically correct.
2. **Make up a name for them in whatever their native language is.** I wouldn't recommend going down this route, it'll probably sound even weirder to your readers. (See [Fiction Rule of Thumb](https://xkcd.com/483/))
3. **Just always use "everyone," "faeries," or another broad term.** But I get the idea you're not planning to go down this road, given that you're asking this here. :)

I hope that helps!